# How to validate android apk file, how does google validates apk and what are the types of validating android apk??

Tags: android, validation, signature

I am actually planning to automate the process of validating the android apk? can any one suggest me what are the types of validations that google performs before they add the apk to playstore.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, I'm afraid you can't do it. APK validation is ran privately by Google. When you upload an application to the playstore you have to complete a series of forms for your APK, this includes things like: Images such as the Appicon and Banners, the age rating for the application you're uploading and the countries/locales your app is available in.

However I think you're talking about the inter-application processing between uploading and the app being live. This is all handled by google, the java that you write is checked by computers over and over in different circumstances in order to ensure that your code isn't doing anything malicious (not that it could these days).